# Pagination link on static page

Tags: wordpress, pagination

The manual pagination is working when I change the page directly in the url. But it's not working with the links, the link is always the page 2.

It's displayed on a static page. I changed get_query_var('paged') to get_query_var('page') to make the pagination (manual) working.

```
<?php
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'post',
'posts_per_page' => 2,
'paged' => ( get_query_var('page') ? get_query_var('page') : 1)
);
query_posts($args);
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
?>
<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php previous_posts_link( 'Older Posts' ); ?>
<?php next_posts_link( 'Newer Posts' ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use, `new WP_Query($args)` An example;

```
<?php 
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'post',
'posts_per_page' => 2,
'paged' => ( get_query_var('page') ? get_query_var('page') : 1)
);
// the query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

    <!-- pagination here -->

    <!-- the loop -->
    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <!-- end of the loop -->

    <!-- pagination here -->

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php else : ?>
    <p><?php esc_html_e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

More details : https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query